# 'or' not working on while-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
print("You see an orc standing in your path. There is no way out but 
through it.")
print("0. Escape\n1. Fight\n2. Defend\n3. Heal")
Action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what to do 
next."))

while Action (!= 0) or (OrcHealth <=0):
    if Action == 1:
        HeroAttack=random.randint(1,5)
        OrcHealth = OrcHealth - HeroAttack
        print("You see an opening, this is your chance! You swing your blade 
        and do",HeroAttack,"to the orc.\n This brings the beast down to", 
        OrcHealth)
        Action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what 
        to do next."))
```

At line 6 I begin my while-loop. It half-works, but when OrcHealth reaches 0 or less the while-loop does not terminate as I intend. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Well, yeah. `OrcHealth <= 0` makes your loop continue while the orc has 0 or less health...

Comment: For starters, that `while` line looks like a syntax error.

Comment: You don't need any parens in your `while` statement

Comment: `(!= 0)` isn't a valid expression. Please don't introduce new errors on top of the one you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You should give  [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
a read.

You can fix your code by switching `or` to `and` and changing the "still alive check" for the orc-health.

I did some tweaks to make it an mvce:

```
import random

print("You see an orc standing in your path. There is no way out but through it.")
print("0. Escape\n1. Fight\n2. Defend\n3. Heal")
Action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what to do next."))
OrcHealth = 50
while (Action != 0) and (OrcHealth > 0):
    if Action == 1:
        HeroAttack=random.randint(1,5)
        OrcHealth = OrcHealth - HeroAttack
        print("You see an opening, this is your chance! You swing your blade and do",
              HeroAttack,"to the orc.\n This brings the beast down to", max(0,OrcHealth))
        Action = int(input("You grip your sword tightly and think about what to do next."))

print("The orc is dead - you win." if OrcHealth <= 0 else 
      "You stumble, the orc chops your head off. You die. Told you: no way out!")
```

Also worth a read: [de Morgans laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) - or how to negate AND/OR'ed logical operations.